# Thicker lines in SSRS Report Builder reports

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

How can I make the graph lines in reports produced by ReportBuilder thicker? For example, I'd like to change the top graph to look like the bottom one:

[image].

Comment: Try to check: https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/629-change-line-width-in-reporting-services-line-graph

Comment: Hi it wasent realy the same but this it was i found so i was a help =)

Answer (score 6):

You can change this by defining the `BorderWith` property of your Chart Series.

[image: Line Graph - Series properties]

In the designer you can simply select the actual lines of the graph.
Or in the Chart Data menu edit the Series Properties like this:

[image: Line Graph - Series properties (2)]